# Can I cleanly delete firebase CLI project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I ran firebase init in the wrong directory and it is connected to my project. To undo that, can I just delete ./firebase.json and my_newly_created_folder_name/ from the terminal? Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem. Firebase CLI should add an option to remove/reset/ or re-initialize a project in a new folder.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should delete `firebase.json` and `.firebaserc` if it exists. Once those files are deleted you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! worked for me to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104731/firebase-init-throws-error-failed-to-get-firebase-project-with-wrong-project-na/72116991#72116991

Answer (score 3):

I am using the following command

```
npm uninstall firebase
```

and

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
```

it works for me

Comment: it removes formModule and post from my http service..... sad

Answer (score 2):

- npm uninstall firebase
- rm -rf firebase.json
- rm -rf .firebase

Answer (score 0):

As for Firebase CLI version 8.4.2, you should delete the folder "functions" as well as the following files: firebase.json, .firebaserc, .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your case do not forget in /.github/workflows you may have CI (Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge) configuration files  **firebase-hosting-merge.yml** and **firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml**.