# firebase init throws Error: failed to get Firebase project with wrong project name

Tags: firebase, init

When I run `firebase init` from my static project directory, project setup fails with this error:

```
Error: Failed to get Firebase project project-name. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.
```

The `project-name` in the error is different from the `projectID` in the `firebaseConfig` script. There is no project listed as `project-name` in my firebase dashboard or project details.
I've tried [logging out and logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63517550/6069097) with [--reauth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68410138/6069097) and [adding a project alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65085624/6069097) but the error is the same and so is the name difference. [Leaving the login browser tab open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67252892/6069097) definitely doesn't work.

It seems like something is going wrong with the project name. How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an older version of my .firebaserc file. Once I deleted that the old [firebase CLI project was fully deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056970/can-i-cleanly-delete-firebase-cli-project) and I was able to run `firebase init` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Add updated project name in .firebaserc file & then firebase init.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).